# C# single instance in more places

Tags: c#, arrays, oop

What will be behavior of this code? Will be s == "changed instance" or s == "initial instance"?

```
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
instance.setName("initial instance")

List<SomeClass> list1 = new List<SomeClass>();
List<SomeClass> list2 = new List<SomeClass>();

list1.add(instance);
list2.add(instance);

list2.get(0).setName("changed instance");
string s = list1.get(0).getName();
```

EDIT: okay, i did some changes to code. I was writing it quite fast.
EDIT2: Why I am asking this and do not try? Because I do not have IDE on this computer due some restrictions.

Comment: Best way to test this kind of question is to ask the compiler.

Comment: You can't call setName/getName directly from the list, they are instance functions.. You'd had to do e.g. list2.First().setName(...

Comment: While we could tell you the behavior, why are you asking us? Just run the program, then you will know. If you have a question that you can't possibly figure out by running the code yourself, then ask it.

Comment: @SWeko see the edit2 and think before you write.

Comment: This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, [see the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Comment: @David the same as above

Comment: It simply does not matter that you do not have an IDE. This is not a site to ask what code will do. Run it. If you can't run it now, wait and run it when you can. At home, at work, wherever. Ther are even websites that actually compile and execute code. This is not the place for this type of question.

Comment: @David I am confused. Can you vindicate your statement?

Comment: @RyanGates can you pinpoint what is wrong? For my better future questions of course.

Comment: The first point is to always post code as a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). The next point is that asking what your code does shows that you have not put in enough effort to try to run it. Lastly, your question should be general enough to provide value to future users.

Comment: @John thought about it, and still feel the same. [This](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php) is the first answer to searching "compile c# online" on google. Second one works too. The problem is not the pseudocode, or that your brackets were not aligned. Asking the same question, with the same source, only with a why instead of a what would have given you a much more positive response on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference. You have two lists that have a reference to the same object. So changing the object in one list will affect it in the other list. If you were to pass a primitive rather than an object, it will be passed by value. When passed by value, it is essentially a copy. So changing the value in one list will not change the value in the other list.

If you want a class to have "value like" behavior, you can can create a method in the class that returns a copy of itself. That is, a new object containing members and properties, etc, set to the same values as the original's.

Example:

```
public SomeClass Clone()
{
    SomeClass newSomeClass = new SomeClass();
    newSomeClass.setName(this.getName());
    return newSomeClass;
}
```

Then the code becomes:

```
SomeClass instance = new SomeClass();
instance.setName("initial instance")

List<SomeClass> list1 = new List<SomeClass>();
List<SomeClass> list2 = new List<SomeClass>();

list1.add(instance);
list2.add(instance.Clone());

list2.get(0).setName("changed instance");
string s = list.get(0).getName();
```

And the result will be that list1 and list2 contain two different SomeClass instances, with different names.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more information about value vs reference types.

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate, because both value types and reference types inherit from `System.Object`.

Comment: True, but MSDN explicitly states that primitives are value types except for the string type. Classes are reference types. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: good to see answer to my question instead of bunch of pedant comments telling the compiler does not take my pseudocode.

Comment: The point is that `SomeClass` _could_ be a value type. If it were, then `SomeStruct` would be a better name, but it's still possible. Value types don't have to be primitives.

Answer (score 3):

When you add an object to two lists, and you change the object in one list, the other list will still refer to the same object, and thus have the updated value.

Comment: Assuming `SomeClass` is a reference type, which sounds like a safe assumption to me.

Answer (score 2):

"Changed instance" since you only created one instance so they share that implementation.

Comment: setName is a method of list item

Comment: I am really pleased by your generous answer, but take this please more like pseudocode. I hope you have as much abstract thinking to understand.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I realized, but I wasn't 100% certain if he was using a default `List<T>` type due to his original form. I was hoping a revision would clarify. A complete answer got posted by the time I went to revise and answer.